# Trouble callings two async functions:

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise, asynchronous-javascript

I have a asynchronous function which calls an external API. I got the results in API variable and console logging produces the right result.

```
function getSourceAndCountry(arr) {
  let source = ``;
  let country = ``;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] && arr[i][j + 1]) {
        let API = `https://coronavirus-tracker-api.herokuapp.com/v2/locations?source=`;
        source = arr[i][j];
        API += `${source}`;
        country = arr[i][j + 1];
        API += `&country_code=${country}`;
        console.log(API);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

console.logging produces the following results after calling: `getSourceAndCountry(sourceToCountry)`

```
https://coronavirus-tracker-api.herokuapp.com/v2/locations?source=csbs&country_code=US
https://coronavirus-tracker-api.herokuapp.com/v2/locations?source=jhu&country_code=CA
https://coronavirus-tracker-api.herokuapp.com/v2/locations?source=jhu&country_code=IN
```

I tried using async-await like this:

```
async function oneTypeMultipleCountries(agent) {...
let response = Promise.resolve(result);
      response.then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });

async function getSourceAndCountry(arr) {
  let source = ``;
  let country = ``;
  let response;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] && arr[i][j + 1]) {
        let API = `https://coronavirus-tracker-api.herokuapp.com/v2/locations?source=`;
        source = arr[i][j];
        API += `${source}`;
        country = arr[i][j + 1];
        API += `&country_code=${country}`;
        response = await getJSON(API);

      }
    }
  }
   return response;
}
```

Console logging the res value in promises produces the last resolved promise. What am I missing here. I am not able to figure out.

Comment: Uh, there is only a single `response` variable in your code, which can only hold a single value. It would behave the same if you were calling a synchronous function in a loop. What result do you actually expect, an array of responses?

Comment: @Bergi It returns a from json an external API.

Answer (score 0):

you may want the function to return a map like this

```js
const getSourceAndCountry = async (arr) => {
  const responses = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] && arr[i][j + 1]) {
        const source = arr[i][j];
        const country = arr[i][j + 1];
        const API = `https://coronavirus-tracker-api.herokuapp.com/v2/locations?source=${source}&country_code=${country}`;
        responses[`${country}:${source}`] = await getJSON(API);
      }
    }
  }
  return response;
}
```